# Why do strings sometimes get changed to numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
function getSessionGUID() {
   return (S4()+S4());
}

function S4() {
   return (((1+Math.random())*0x10000)|0).toString(16).substring(1);
}
```

It clearly returns a string, but if you run it a bunch of times, you can notice that it sometimes returns infinity.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++){ if(getSessionGUID() == Infinity) console.log("INFINITY"); }
871 x INFINITY
```

I then noticed that if you remove the |0, it solves the problem:

```
function S4() {
   return (((1+Math.random())*0x10000)|0).toString(16).substring(1);
}
```

Results:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++){ if(getSessionGUID() == Infinity) console.log("INFINITY"); }
undefined
```

Why does this happen? In both cases the value is changed into a string.

Comment: is it random, or at particular values of `i`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This test reveals the answer:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
  var x=getSessionGUID();
  if(x == Infinity) console.log(x); }
}
```

It logs values like `61e93284` or `1413e390`

These values are valid numbers and they are way too big for the Number type, so they get cast as Infinity when interpreted as a number.

If you replace `==` with `===` in the test, no conversion occurs and nothing is logged. The conversion is caused by the `==` operator.

Answer (score 3):

You are generating hexidecimal strings.

When you use the `==` operator, the interpreter tries to coerce the two values to the same data type. When comparing strings to `Infinity`, that intermediate data type is `Number`. When those strings contain the letter "e" (a valid hexidecimal digit) and they're coerced to a `Number`, javascript interprets this as 10^x which ends up as some huge number.

[`Number`s in javascript are 8 bytes](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Number_Reference), so anything larger than `1.7976931348623157e308` is considered equal to `Infinity`.

The easiest way to fix this is to change your `==` to `===` so the string doesn't get coerced to a number.

```
if(getSessionGUID() === Infinity)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Uhkxm/

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is dynamically typed.  There isn't an integer,  floating point.  String data type.  All of that conversions is done internally depending on the context.

The + could be string concatenation or addition depending on context.

Edit: Apologies. Too late. But it was the == performing the conversion to number when comparing against infinity.  In some cases, you generated valid numbers.

Comment: Under which circumstances does `String + String == Infinity`? `S4` doesn't seem to ever return a Number

Comment: The `+` operator doesn't cause the infinity.

Comment: I realized that the moment I posted.  Damn phone wasn't letting me edit the post! :( (sorry... )

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out. There's actually nothing wrong in all of this, except on my test code.

If you take this string "11e51354", you can get it to assert to true since Javascript checks for all the types that could make it equal to true.

```
"11e51354" == Infinity # True
```

The right test would be:

```
"11e51354" === Infinity # False
```

It's still a string, but somehow while I was sending it through a GET request, it was being transformed into a number type which gave Infinity.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a number type, you always could use following.
 `console.log(Number("1"));`

Comment: I need a String type, but it converts into Infinity sometimes when I use the value in a GET request.

Comment: it's generally better to specify the type of number you need (e.g. `Integer()`) than to be generic. Specifying `Number()` simply reduces the number of possible targets for type coercion.

Comment: Moox: That's still highly bizarre. I've NEVER seen a string converted to Infinity in five years of web development. Do you know what specific strings this is happening to?

Comment: @sudowned check my response. I'll look into my code for my GET request and get back to this thread for more details.

Comment: @sudowned The value is actually being placed into a cookie. I guess it depends on the browser, some typing might get lost in the process and the value is saved into the cookie as a number which changes to Infinity. Although this is a weird problem, the fix is just to add any non-numerical characters in mix (S4() + "-" + S4()).